# Array is failing to accept data

Tags: php, arrays

> **Concept:** User enters his/her postcode (**EXA1 2PL** OR **EX1 2AP**) we trim the last 3 characters and are left with the start of the postcode (**EXA1** OR **EX1**); Now we check the data against the array and if it matches do something else do something else.

When processing users data I always end up getting the array output with nothing in it. Below is the code that I'm using.

```
$op_postcodes = '"PH3,PH4,PH5"';
//Data has been cut for stack purposes however stays in same format
//with one " at the start of the string and one at the end

$op_postcodes = str_replace(',', '","', $op_postcodes);
$op_postcodes = array($op_postcodes);
```

This outputs: `Array` and fails to be able to match with users input

I'm very sorry if you can't understand what I am talking about. My English isn't too good.

Comment: use `explode` to create the array

Comment: @explode can you leave this as an answer that way I can give you credit if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, if you use `explode` you will get an array with more than one element which is what your current method does. However, I'm not sure why you would want to encapsulate the array values in quotes as you do?

```
$op_postcodes = '"PH3,PH4,PH5"';
$op_postcodes = str_replace(',', '","', $op_postcodes);
$op_postcodes = explode(',', $op_postcodes);

echo in_array( '"PH4"', $op_postcodes ) ? 'Found it' : 'Ooops, could not find it';
```

Unless there is a specific need to encapsulate the array values within quotes then a minor alteration to the above could be:

```
$search_user_value='PH4';

$op_postcodes = '"PH3,PH4,PH5"';
$op_postcodes = str_replace('"', '', $op_postcodes );
$op_postcodes = explode(',', $op_postcodes);
echo in_array( $search_user_value, $op_postcodes ) ? 'Found it' : 'Ooops, could not find it';
```

Comment: The "encapsulate in quotes" is probably just confusion from the regular array syntax, array("PH3", "PH4", "PH5") etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and @MatsLindh that's sort of what I was trying to do however I have removed this and it is now working fine!